# Add PostgreSQL column constraint based on value in other column(s)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectCreationTasks 
(
    Id           text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProjectName  text,
    ProjectCode  text,
    DenialReason text
);
```

An administrator can approve or deny a project creation request. To approve, the admin sets both a ProjectName and ProjectCode; to deny, the admin sets a DenialReason.

How can I add a constraint such that:

1. `Name`, `Code`, `Reason` can all be null simultaneously
2. If both `Name` and `Code` has a value then `Reason` must be null
3. If `Reason` has a value, then both `Name` and `Code` must be null

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a side note you should normalize this if you can. This is not a sound schema nor practice. When you start asking yourself these kinds of question you should consider tweaking your design (which is easy in this case).

Answer (score 5):

You could use `CHECK` constaint to implement this kind of logic:

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectCreationTasks ( 
Id                  text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ProjectName         text,
ProjectCode         text,
DenialReason        text,
CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK
((ProjectName IS NULL AND ProjectCode IS NULL AND DenialReason IS NULL)
 OR(ProjectName IS NOT NULL AND ProjectCode IS NOT NULL AND DenialReason IS NULL)
 OR(DenialReason IS NOT NULL AND ProjectName IS NULL AND ProjectCode IS NULL))
);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7719a33e479a984ace73770b26f257d3)**

Comment: I believe `OR((ProjectName IS NOT NULL AND ProjectCode IS NOT NULL) AND DenialReason IS NULL)` should be  `OR((ProjectName IS NOT NULL AND ProjectCode IS NOT NULL) AND DenialReason IS NULL)`

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Please check my db fiddle demo. I treat `2) if Name/Code has a value then Reason must be null,` as `OR` and it works OK. I would be greatful if you could provide counterexample.

Comment: My reading of the OP's rule is that if DenialReason IS NULL, _both_ ProjectName and ProjectCode must be filled in. `INSERT INTO ProjectCreationTasks VALUES (5, 'PName', NULL, NULL);` succeeds (added to your DBFiddle) but should _fail_.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus your reading is correct. If name has a value, so must code. Likewise if code has a value, so must name.

Comment: In this case, this answer will do what you want, but with the change of OR to AND indicated in my first comment.

Comment: @mkhira2 Changed `OR` to `AND`. For next time please be specific `\` is mostly treated as alternative.

Comment: The enumerated reasons were indeed very ambiguous. My clue was the narrative: "To approve, the admin sets _both_ a ProjectName and ProjectCode;" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Lukasz Szozda is correct as modified in my comment (the problem statement is slightly ambiguous). A slightly shorter equivalent clause that might be harder to read is

```
CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK
((ProjectName IS NULL = ProjectCode IS NULL) -- go together
    AND (ProjectCode IS NULL OR DenialReason IS NULL) -- allow both NULL but disallow both NOT NULL
);
```